# Find (1-p)/(1-q) where p and q are polynomials (AR-representation)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, time-series

In the book Analysis of Financial Time Series by Tsay, there is a certain representation of an [AR-model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model) there is a little algebraic identity I cannot see why it is true, highlighted in blue in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check
$$
(1-\phi_1B)(1-\theta_1B)\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(\phi_1B)^i = 1-\theta_1B
$$
to see that the equality is indeed true.

To get an intuitive feeling where it comes from you can use the identity for a geometric series.
$$
\frac{1-\theta_1B}{1-\phi_1B} = (1-\theta_1B)\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(\phi_1B)^i.
$$

However, if you want to formally derive this you need to calculate the Laurent series representation of this function on an annulus around the unit circle (note that you then assume there are no poles on the unit circle). You can check [this](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~gugushvilis/dictaat.pdf) text bij Van Der Vaart, specifically the beginning of chapter 8.

Comment: I thought I was done when you mentioned the geometric series. I am naive here so how come it's not enough with just the geometric series formula?

Comment: Well the geometric series formula is officially meant for real numbers. Even though it works for polynomials too, that might not be necessarily "trivial". The method that usually is applied to fractions of complex polynomials is the Laurent series, which always works. It's not that important if you don't know the theory. I wanted to mention it just in case though;)